# How OpenRasta internally works?

Tags: openrasta

So far I only found documentation about how to use OpenRasta and the great functionality it provides, but Is there some kind of documentation or diagrams that helps to understand its internal architecture, components and how they interact between them, how a resources and handlers are internally registered and the entire life cycle of a request?
Having a better understanding on the OpenRasta internal components may help to extend it or customize it for specific scenarios.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No there's no such content, can definitely see why it'd be useful.